# Disable auto-compositing in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-studio

I've got a style in Mapbox Studio which, like all styles, has composited my layers with Mapbox layers into a single set of vector tiles. I'd actually prefer my source data to be kept separate (so I can manipulate it with Mapbox-GL-JS).

[image]

Is there a way to disable the automatic compositing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over in the top right under Debug, then at the bottom of the panel you can turn compositing off:

[image: Mapbox Studio Source compositing]

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I looked everywhere - didn't think of there though.